# Laravel and Dropbox file permissions conflict

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, dropbox, file-permissions

I'm running apache on my Mac and have a website folder in Dropbox so I can work from a few different machines. Laravel works if `/app/storage` is `775`. If `750`, Laravel doesn't work. However, with the permission at `775`, Dropbox tries to sync and fails with an "access denied" error.

I tried enabling Dropbox selective sync and unchecked the `app/storage` folder but it removed it completely from my computer which obviously breaks Laravel.

How can I make Dropbox and Laravel friends again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get Dropbox to ignore the folder by [following these steps](http://aurelio.net/articles/dropbox-ignore-folder.html).

I ignored the sessions and views folders but I may have only needed to ignore the sessions folder. I am not sure.

The steps were:

1. Copy the `/apps/storage/views` and `/apps/storage/sessions` folders
   to your desktop
2. Delete the originals in `/apps/storage/views` and
   `/apps/storage/sessions`
3. Create empty view and session folders in `/apps/storage/`
4. Turn on selective sync via Dropbox and uncheck the
   `/apps/storage/views` and `/apps/storage/sessions`
5. Both folders will be deleted by dropbox, re-add the copies you made
   on your desktop.

Dropbox sync should not have any more conflicts and will now ignore files in views and sessions folders.